# Fatal error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application mvn client:build

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

I'm facing problem while I try to client:build it works perfect when I run client:runagent. but when I do client:build it's showing this error

```
We will now compile your code for x86_64-microsoft-windows. This may take some time.
[Wed May 26 06:36:41 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] [org.suleiman.app:12956]    classlist:   3,075.21 ms,  0.96 GB
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Fatal error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoaderSupport.loadClassFromModule(NativeImageClassLoaderSupport.java:100)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageClassLoader.loadClassFromModule(ImageClassLoader.java:416)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:311)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:529)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:119)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:561)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 18 more
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][INFO] Additional information: Objectfile should be called org.suleiman.app.obj but we didn't find that under F:\JavaFX\TouchControl\JoyStick-Conttrol-In-JavaFX-for-Touch-Devices\target\client\x86_64-windows\gvm
[Wed May 26 06:36:45 PKT 2021][SEVERE] Compiling failed.
```

Comment: Can you check that under `target/client/x86-64-windows/gvm/tmp/deps` you see the JavaFX jars?

Comment: yes, I can see the JavaFX-base.jar at that path.

Comment: The log under `target/client/x86_64-windows/gvm/log` should have enough information about the compile task and the classpath used, see if it makes sense to you or post more details

Comment: I don't understand why it's giving this cause Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application  it's in the log file.

Comment: Sir can you help me to understand deployment in JavaFX https://meet.google.com/ygy-bgnx-rkf

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue earlier. My problem was that the scope of the org.openjfx dependencies was set to "provided" and didn't get included.